# How to remove the portion of a String with Java or Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, substring

I have string:

```
John Smith [birth. 1970-07-05] [Doctor degree from 2016-01-01]
```

I need to modify this string by removing only middle part of the string the birth date part ( in my case `[birth. 1970-07-05]`) leaving other bits: the *first name*, *lastname* and *doctor degree*.

In *JasperReports* it is only allowed to enter so called 'text field expression', so i came up with this:

```
$P{AUTHOR}.indexOf("[") < 0 ? $P{AUTHOR} : $P{AUTHOR}.substring(0,$P{AUTHOR}.indexOf("[")-1)
```

It works till the person does not have any degree, so it removes only birth date, but when a degree occurs, it also removes degree as well.

Something I am missing.

Comment: You can use regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$P{AUTHOR}.indexOf("[") < 0 
    ? $P{AUTHOR} 
    : $P{AUTHOR}.substring(0,$P{AUTHOR}.indexOf("[")) 
       + ($P{AUTHOR}.indexOf("[", $P{AUTHOR}.indexOf("[") + 1) > -1 
         ? $P{AUTHOR}.substring( $P{AUTHOR}.indexOf("[", $P{AUTHOR}.indexOf("[") + 1)) 
         : "")
```

Answer (score 0):

The first that comes to mind is a regex:

$P{AUTHOR}.replaceAll(Pattern.quote('[birth.') + '.*' + Pattern.quote('] '), '')

Answer (score 0):

If the birth information is always in the second position, splits and joins would suffice:

```
'John Smith [birth. 1970-07-05] [Doctor degree from 2016-01-01]'
        .split(/\[/)[0, 2]     // split by open bracket, take the 1st and 3rd segment
        .join('[')             // join the segments back again
```

The above produces the string `John Smith [Doctor degree from 2016-01-01]`